What is the Fourier transform of a train of square waves?
I've read that the Fourier series is used for periodic functions, and that the Fourier transform is used for both periodic and aperiodic functions.  Sines and cosines are periodic and their Fourier transforms are well-known; much less info seems to be out there on the Fourier transform of a square wave train. If anyone can explain why this is as well as how to derive it or point to a source, I'd be very appreciative.

what's a square train? a pulse train? a square wave?

I suggest to think about a periodic function $x(t)$ with period $T$ as a convolution of a kernel function $x_{\text{ker}}(t)$ with a train of impulses, which are $T$ apart, and use the convolution property and Poisson summation to get the Fourier transform of the underlying periodic function.

What in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_wave doesn't answer your question ?

I'm not going to answer your question directly, as this is a classic homework problem, but here are some hints (expanding a bit on @AHT's comment):

Model $x(t)$ as $x(t) = rect(t/W)*comb_{T}(t)$, where $rect(t/W)$ is a single rectangle of width $W$ centered at $t=0$, "$*$" is convolution, and $comb_{T}(t) = \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty \delta (t-kT)$.
Find the Fourier Transform of the $rect(t/W)$ and $comb_T(t)$ functions.
Use the Convolution theorem to get the Fourier Transform of $x(t)$

